# Creating a list of matching/containing strings

Tags: php, regex

How can I get a list of strings that contain matching strings' value?

Let me try to explain that a little better.

Here is my input string (whole thing is one string):

> You have moved left 55 spaces. You have moved right 23 spaces. You have moved left 71 spaces. You have jumped up. You have moved left 2 spaces. You have moved left 88 spaces. You have jumped down. You have jumped up. You have moved right 131 spaces. You have jumped down.

What I want to do is get a list of all the move directions and its number of spaces.  So, I would have to search through the string and look for all the 'You have moved [direction] [numspaces] spaces.' and somehow store that [direction] into a list and [numspaces] into another list.

So, in the end, my list for direction would have:

> left
>   right
>   left
>   left
>   right

And my list for numspaces would have:

> 55
>   23
>   71
>   2
>   131

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'You have moved left 55 spaces. You have moved right 23 spaces. You have moved left 71 spaces. You have jumped up. You have moved left 2 spaces. You have moved left 88 spaces. You have jumped down. You have jumped up. You have moved right 131 spaces. You have jumped down.';

$directions = array('left', 'right');

$directions_regex = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $directions));

preg_match_all("~($directions_regex)\s+(\d+)~", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/NhdrGT

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$str = 'You have moved left 55 spaces. You have moved right 23 spaces. You have moved left 71 spaces. You have jumped up. You have moved left 2 spaces. You have moved left 88 spaces. You have jumped down. You have jumped up. You have moved right 131 spaces. You have jumped down.';

preg_match_all('/You have moved (left|right) (\d+) spaces/', $str, $matches);
array_shift($matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => left [1] => right [2] => left [3] => left [4] => left [5] => right ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 23 [2] => 71 [3] => 2 [4] => 88 [5] => 131 ) )
```